# How to find out phone's date of manufacture?

Tags: lumia-520

Recently I got a Lumia 520 as a gift from my niece and, being a newbie to Windows Phone, I don't know anything about its software.

Now I want to know, is there a way by which we can know the date of manufacture of a Windows Phone device?

Answer (score 1):

On older Nokia phones (pre-Lumia), codes could be entered that would show the warranty status (ie. manufacture date) but these do not work.

So, without a special Nokia app or some other new method, the only way to tell is to look on the box your Lumia was packaged in...

[image]

Source: [WP Central forums](http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-1020/288633-possible-find-manufacturer-date.html)

Comment: thanks for your assistance but i dont havethe box

Comment: @agharehanabbas then there is no way to find the manufacture date unless you visit a Nokia Service Center

Answer (score -1):

*#92702689# Displays - 1.Serial Number, 2.Date Made, 3.Purchase Date, 4.Date of last repair (0000 for no repairs), 5.Transfer User Data. To exit this mode you need to switch your phone off then on again

*#92702689#*3370# Warranty details

Comment: Doesn't work on my Lumia 920.